# All VMware software & their installers fail to start, all of sudden, with no error messages & without getting listed in Task Manager

Tags: windows-7, windows, vmware-workstation

I have been using VMware Player on a Windows 7 machine.

Today I noticed that my VMware player wasn't starting so tried to repair it using the installer but even that failed to start. After clicking to run VMware player & allowing admin permissions, the program just doesn't start.

I even tried installing the latest version of VMware but that too failed. Nothing happens when I try to start VMware Player or its installer. Everything works fine on my computer apart from that.

Now I tried to install the fresh trial version of VMware workstation, that installer even fails to start.
Previously everything used to work fine.

### Why is the whole product family of VMware failing to start now?

Very occasionally I saw this error when trying to run the installer:[image]

### Edit:

I don't know what to look into the Event logs.. here is a snapshot of the application logs listed for Vmware:

[image]

Here are the details of one of those logs:-

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        VMware NAT Service
Date:          21-01-2012 19:19:07
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Rajat-PC
Description:
The description for Event ID 1000 from source VMware NAT Service cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

Using configuration file: C:\ProgramData\VMware\vmnetnat.conf.
IP address: 192.168.186.2
 Subnet: 255.255.255.0
External IP address: 0.0.0.0
Device: vmnet8.
MAC address: 00:50:56:EC:E3:0A.
Ignoring host MAC address: 00:50:56:C0:00:08.


Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="VMware NAT Service" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-01-21T13:49:07.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>24656</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Rajat-PC</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Using configuration file: C:\ProgramData\VMware\vmnetnat.conf.
IP address: 192.168.186.2
 Subnet: 255.255.255.0
External IP address: 0.0.0.0
Device: vmnet8.
MAC address: 00:50:56:EC:E3:0A.
Ignoring host MAC address: 00:50:56:C0:00:08.
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

### Details of a vmauthd error:

```
  Log Name:      Application
Source:        vmauthd
Date:          14-01-2012 12:37:05
Event ID:      100
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Rajat-PC
Description:
The description for Event ID 100 from source vmauthd cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

Failed to read registry perf object Process\ID Process


Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="vmauthd" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">100</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-01-14T07:07:05.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>24291</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Rajat-PC</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Failed to read registry perf object Process\ID Process
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Details included in all the error logs for vmauthd:

```
Failed to read registry perf object Memory\Committed Bytes

Failed to read registry perf object Memory\Page Faults/sec

Error 232 while sending PID reply

Failed to read registry perf object Memory\Cache Bytes

Failed to read registry perf object Process\ID Process

Failed to read registry perf object Memory\Pool Nonpaged Bytes

Failed to read registry perf object Memory\Pool Paged Bytes

Error 232 while sending ERROR reply
```

Comment: How does "failing to start" appear to you? Is there just no window opening? Do you see an error message? Is the installation task still showing up under *Task Manager*?

Comment: did you try a different VMware?

Comment: @slhck: there is no window opened... no error messages.. just nothing when i click it to run the program.. only the windows asks me if I confirm admin's permission to run program.. then simply nothing! not even in task manager!

Comment: @ThatGuy: yes i tried even diffeerent version of VMware players & then tried installing VMware workstation but same issue with the all!

Comment: @user: What did you do to delete my answer?

Comment: @David: This is a fresh post..previous deleted

Comment: @user: Did you tried a virus scan? I've found some post about similar problems and it was a virus or malware problem.

Comment: @user; if you are using Windows 7, check the Event Log, (open start menu, type Event Viewer), and open the Windows Log -> Application Logs, and check for any messages.  This usually is a very good way to figure out what is going on.

Comment: @user: Is this your own PC, or is it administered by someone else?

Comment: @zackrspv: I could see some logs for VMware listed over there.. I have no idea what to inspect over there. I have included a snapshot of what it look like & details of one of those logs.

Comment: @HughAllen: yes this is my own PC & i am the admin

Comment: @user, i would be more interested in the `vmauthd` errors.  Could you provide details on those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing above worked. Then I just uninstalled my 8.x version of VMware, rebooted system & downloaded & installed a fresh latest VMware 9.x which runs fine now!

Answer (score 7):

From what I see from the log entries there, you have a `vmauthd` error.  This error usually prevents you from starting any type of VM on the machine; this can be caused through several issues:

- The service itself is stopped/disabled
- The licence key is expired
- The service is not found.

Given the `vmauthd` error details you have provided, unfortunately doesn't answer the question, given that the actual error from `vmauthd` didn't return any details back to windows.  So, now, we need to do some basic troubleshooting, to ensure that the VMware is setup properly on the system:

### Recovery Options

In situations where applications just will not install, or under normal circumstances nothing works, there are a few additional steps to consider:

**Alternate Profile**:  Creating an alternate user profile on the computer can help to install software, or work with Operating System components that otherwise may be locked, corrupted, or otherwise denied access on the primary profile.

- Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- Type in `control userpasswords2` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard

[image: user account screenshot]

- Click **Add...** to get to the 'Add New User...' screen

[image: test user screenshot]

- Fill in the necessary information.
- Click on <kbd>Next</kbd>
- You can enter a **password** if you wish, I just usually leave it blank, as it will be just a temporary account.

[image: user group screen]

- Select the **Administrators** option, so that you have proper control on the machine.
- Click on <kbd>Finish</kbd> to finish adding the user to the computer.

You can then go ahead and completely restart the computer, and log directly into the test account.  **Try to run** the VMWare Player installer (not the workstation one), to see if it installs.

---

**System Restore**:  The other option that is available to you is to run System Restore.  This is a good feature of Windows that allows the user to restore their machine back to a previous state in time.  Given that you know when the last time it WAS working, you should be able to restore just prior to that and see if your applications start.

---

### Additional Troubleshooting

**Service Verification**

VMWare Player 4.02x should have the following after install:

[image: services]

You can verify this information by doing the following:

- **Click Start**
- Type in:  `services.msc`
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard.

That will bring up your Service console.  Make sure those services exist.  IF THEY DO NOT, you will need to re-install VMWare Player 4.02x.

**Service Configuration**

1. Make sure that the **VMware Authentication Service** is running.  [Not disabled, not stopped].
2. Make sure that the **VMware Authentication service** is set to run as `Local System Account`.
3. **IF THIS IS A SERVER SETUP**:  Make sure that the `netlogon` service is Set to `Automatic` and not disabled or manual.

**User Configuration**

- Make sure the user is either an **Administrator**, or that the Virtual Machine is setup on a local system account, so that when started, it runs with the proper credentials.
- For Windows 7 and Vista with **User Account Control Enabled**:  Make sure you set the VMWare Workstation/appliance executable files to always run as administrator.

**Performance Counters:** information you provided, please run the following from the Command Line via an Elevated Command prompt:

> LODCTR /R

This command rebuilds the perf registry strings and info from scratch based on the current registry settings and backup INI files.

You can also run this from an actual script (once you run this, run the script anyway, just to make sure that your services are setup properly as well, then try your images).

**Application Scripting/Testing**:

You could create a nice batch file that includes the following:

```
lodctr /r
net stop vmauthdservice
net start vmauthdservice
```

And then run it whenever you have issues.  Note, this isn't available on Windows XP, but on Vista, 7, and above, you can run this.  Make sure you run from an **ELEVATED** command prompt:

- Click **Start**
- Type in **'cmd'** into the search bar at the bottom
- **Right Click** on the `cmd` result in the list above
- **Click** on `Run as Administrator...`

Then execute the commands above.

This little script rebuilds the proper performance strings/counters for Virtual Machines on the system, starts and stops the VM Authentication and Registration Services.

You can then just go ahead and try out your VM images again.

Comment: added details of vmauthd errors. Please let me know if you need anything more.

Comment: added info listed in all vmauthd errors..

Comment: - Added more details based on information from OP.

Comment: I can run other virtual machine softwares like VirtualBox, *but not any from VMware*. I am using free VMware player so must not be a license issue. I run the commands you told, in the cmd, it successfully rebuilt the performance counters but the next 2 commands were not successful with message:  `The service name is invalid`. (I was inside c:\ while running these commands)

Comment: where do I test whether VMware Authentication Service is running or not ? I am trying to run the installer of VMware prodcuts but they also fail.

Comment: Please check the Services Verification section of my post for the services that exist for VMWare Player FREE version 4.02. If you do not have those, you need to reinstall.

Comment: my `services.msc` doesn't contain these services, but the point is that VMware player was uninstalled by me earlier & right now I am trying to run the installer itself & not the program, & **the installer itself fails to start**! **Installers of VMware player, workstation all fail to start on my computer**

Comment: @zackrspv: Be warned about this user. I already gave him the same advice with Event Log and Process Monitor but he deleted my answer and started a new one. With this error there are some needles in Google. It can be a virus or so. Just stay away from this user.

Comment: @David: you are taking me wrong, i just voted to delete my question (& not your answer, I dont have the rights to do so! :)). My intention to delete the question was just to get some response as there were no responses on that post except your comments.. so to fresh activate that i created a new question.

Comment: @user: I didn't comment about your question I make an anwser exactly the same as zackrspv suggest you in the comment. Run Event Log and start installer with Process Monitor. You make me look like a dumb and asking me a hundred question in the comment eating my time and finally deleted the answer.

Comment: Please check out this about cleaning up your system before doing a fresh VMWare Install:  http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1308.

Comment: @user, did you try the clean install instructions above?

Comment: @zackrspv: Thanks! yes I did tried these suggestions... most of the places Vmware entries were not there since I had completed a successful installation of VMware player earlier & the rest of places I have removed now but still no success while trying to start the installer..

Comment: The screenshot shows you are installing VMWare Workstation, and not the actual VMWare Player; which one do you wish to install?

Comment: actually I tried another(VM workstation) when the first (VMware player) didn't worked.. I'm looking to install VMware player but workstation would also do.

Comment: Please take a look at the `Recovery Options` I added to the post, and give those two options a try.  Try the alternate profile first, then hit up system restore as a last resort.  Give us an update when that is all done.

Comment: I tried creating new account but it didnt helped; but the good news is that issues has been resolved now!  it was due to a web camera service was running on startup, I disabled that(*through msconfig utility*) and every thing now works perfectly. But I would award this bounty to you for the time you have taken out to help me out. Thankyou!

Comment: @user Please answer your question yourself using the **answer your question** button below. You can then accept it. You shouldn't post the *solution* into the *question*, that doesn't make sense, does it? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Some advice found [here](http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-100-source-vmauthd-eventno-2199-phase-1.htm) :

> In my case, VMware was trying to access network adapters but the
>   adapters were unfortunately missing the "VMware Bridge Protocol",
>   thus, causing the vmauthd service to fail.
>
> In your Network Connections folder, go to the properties of each
>   network adapter (except the virtual VMware adapters...VMnet1, VMnet8,
>   etc). Under the "This connection uses the following items:" section,
>   be sure you have "VMware Bridge Protocol" installed and that it is
>   checked.
>
> If it is not installed, click "Install" --> "Service" --> "Add" -->
>   "Have Disk" --> Browse to your "C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware
>   Workstation". Click OK. This should find the netbridge.inf file and
>   let you choose the Bridging protocol again.

Comment: I'm trying to run the installer right now as I had uninstalled the VMware player when i found it not working; Now I am making reinstallation attempts and this installer behaves in the same way the player was behaving  ie, no response at all. There are no error messages on starting the installer and it just doesnt start. **the installers of VMware player, workstation all fail to start on my computer**

Comment: Have you tried to disable all anti-virus, firewall or other security software?

Comment: yes I have disabled the antivirus & firewall. and the same installation files were previously used to do successful installation

Comment: Does this also happen when booting in Safe mode ?

Comment: will need to test this.. will let you know..

Comment: it works in safe mode!!

Comment: Then this is caused by a product that starts with the computer. You can locate it using a product such as [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) to turn off startup items by groups until you locate the one that conflicts with vmware.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this issue in this thread: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/408832

If you don't see anything happen at all, this might be due to a conflict with a process "fixcamera.exe". If this process is running, kill it in the task manager and start the Player installation again.

It looks like the vmware installer was shy and wouldn't start if there is a webcam process running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who has problems installing VMWare on Windows 7.
Go to start, type in msconfig and enter. At the first tab, select Diagnostic startup, aply and exit. Restart your pc. After reboot, go to start and type services.msc, double click on Windows Management Instrumentation and change it to manual, then start the service. Do the same for Windows Installer service.
Install VMware Workstation without any errors. At the end of the installation, don't restart your pc when prompted to do so, instead start up msconfig again and change back to Normal startup. Aply, exit and reboot.